# How to stop a macro by clicking a command button?

Tags: vba

I have a code to copy a range and paste the values.

This is done in a time interval after I click a command button.

How do I stop or pause this macro by clicking a button?

Here is the main code:

```
Sub timestamp()
'
' timestamp Macro
'   
    N = WorksheetFunction.Count(Sheets("DNB").Columns(1))   

    dnbspread = Sheets("DNB").Range("G5:G30")

    Sheets("DNB").Cells(N + 34, 1) = Date
    Sheets("DNB").Cells(N + 34, 2) = Time
    Sheets("DNB").Range("G5:G30").Copy

    Sheets("DNB").Cells(N + 34, 3).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "timestamp"

End Sub
```

I tried a couple of things.

> 1. by BREAK function

```
Sub PauseMacro()
    Application.SendKeys "^{BREAK}"
End Sub
```

> 2.

```
Public StopMacro as Boolean
Sub SetStopMacro()
    StopMacro = True
End Sub
```

and put it in the code as this:

```
Sub timestamp()
'

' timestamp Macro

'
    N = WorksheetFunction.Count(Sheets("DNB").Columns(1))

    dnbspread = Sheets("DNB").Range("G5:G30")

    Sheets("DNB").Cells(N + 34, 1) = Date

    Sheets("DNB").Cells(N + 34, 2) = Time

    Sheets("DNB").Range("G5:G30").Copy

    Sheets("DNB").Cells(N + 34, 3).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "timestamp"

    DoEvents

    If StopMacro = True Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: If Not StopMacro Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "timestamp"
    End If

Comment: Thanks for input.
Not sure how to put it in and what to include. I get "End if without block if" error.

Comment: There is a difference between pausing or stopping? Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public StopMacro As Boolean

Sub SetStopMacro()
    StopMacro = True
End Sub

Sub timestamp()
    '
    ' timestamp Macro
    '
    ' code here
    '
    ' Put If-Then before Application.OnTime call. 
    ' So prevent next call of 'timestamp()' if StopMacro equals to true
    If Not StopMacro Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "timestamp"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a global variable inside the module where the macro is running from, and then, when the command button is clicked, assign a value to that variable you just declared.  Then, create an if statement, where the code exits if the variable equals to that value.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()   
btncancel = 1
EMSetup.hide
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

For the command button.

```
Global btncancel As Integer
If btncancel = 1 Then
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Hope this helps!